# For loop on dict not working after performing a list comprehension

Tags: python, file, list

I'm writing some python code that's supposed to parse a CSV file. Calculate the mean value of a specific row and then send an email to recipients based on the values of one row in the CSV file. My code is as follows, I've removed the email sending code for now and replaced it with a print statement:

```
def main():
  #smtp_instance = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
  ldap_file = open('ldaps.csv','rU')
  ldap_data=csv.DictReader(ldap_file) 
  scores = list(int(d['score']) for d in ldap_data)

  average_score = sum(scores) / len(scores)
  print average_score

  for rows in ldap_data:
    ldap = rows['ldap']
    fullname = rows['fullname']
    firstname = fullname.split(' ')[0]
    location = rows['location']
    score = rows['score']
    if int(score) < average_score:
      score_msg = 'below'
    else:
      score_msg = 'above'

    print 'Hi ' + firstname + '\n'\
          'You got a ' + score + '% on your Final Exam.'\
          'The average score was ' + average_score + '.'\
          'This means that you scored ' + score_msg + ' average.'

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

When I run this it prints the average_score value. But the code never gets to the for..loop. It seems that I can't call a list comprehension on the dict and then iterate on the same dict. Any idea what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix it?

Comment: Try just printing `ldap_data` before and after the comprehension, if you think it's getting damaged. Or step through it with `pdb` and check the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reader objects returned by the `csv` module behave as generators, they can only be iterated over once. If you want a real list that you can iterate repeatedly, you have to create on explicitly:

```
ldap_data = list(csv.DictReader(ldap_file))
```

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
scores = list(int(d['score']) for d in ldap_data)
```

consumes all the data in `ldap_data`. `ldap_data` is an iterator driven by the underlying data in the file `ldap_file`. As you iterate through `ldap_data`, the underlying file `ldap_file` is consumed.

So `ldap_data` is empty when it reaches the `for-loop`.

```
for rows in ldap_data:
```

One way around this is to make `ldap_data` a list:

```
ldap_data  = list(csv.DictReader(ldap_file))
```

Another way around this is to tell `ldap_file` to read from the beginning again:

```
scores = list(int(d['score']) for d in ldap_data)
...
ldap_file.seek(0)  
...
for rows in ldap_data:
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because `ldap_data` is a reader object which only supports iterator protocol. That means you can only iterate it once, which you do when you create `scores` list.

You have to either put it in a collection or, if the file is too big, read it again before looping.

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of ldap data?

I have a feeling it's an iterator, not a list, so if you iterate through it once (eg in the list comprehension), the next time you try to iterate through it will throw "StopIteration" immediately.

Try copying it to a list immediately after

```
ldap_data = csv.DictReader(ldap_file) 
ldap_data = list(ldap_data)
```